# Pepper: accesing project folder via ssh

Tags: python, pepper

I have accessed to Pepper robot via **ssh**. My intention is to find the project folder to see where files are created when the robot create a file via

```
file = open('test.txt', 'w')
file.write('testing how to save project data')
file.close()
```

the problem is that I don't know where is saved the project, anyone knows in which path is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pure .py script, add this to your script and you will find the directory:

```
import os
strPath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
print strPath
```

If your project is installed with Choregraphe, the general directory is `/var/persistent/home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps`
So assuming your .py file is located in the root directory of your project, test.txt will be located in `/var/persistent/home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/<project_name>/test.txt`

**Edit:**

For code inside Choregraphe the solution looks differently.

```
self.behaviorPath = ALFrameManager.getBehaviorPath(self.behaviorId)
self.logger.info(self.behaviorPath)
```

Comment: what should **__file__** be? the name of the project?

Comment: Python has "magic methods". Just leave it as it is. You can google them; __file__, __main__, __version__, __doc__, etc,

Comment: seems that he can't know what *__file__ is* `global name '__file__' is not defined`. Pepper works using Linux, so it should work, and the project is made with *Choregraphe*

Comment: Seems that Choreographe is saving the file inside a folder named 'data'. So I needed to know where was the project to see where files are created. The project is in `/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/.lastUploadedChoregrapheBehavior/behavior_1`.
 Thanks for the help